# How to enforce matrix invertibility in optimisation problem?

Tags: optimization

I want to find a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ satisfying:
\begin{align}
Ax & \leq b,\\
Ac & = d,
\end{align}
with $b\in\mathbb{R}^{n},c\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $d\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ known vectors.

My idea is to find a $J\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ that satisfies:
\begin{align}
J & \leq b,\\
Ac & = d,\\
A&\text{ invertible}
\end{align}
Then $x = A^{-1}J$.

1) Is there a better way of solving my original problem?

2) If my idea is good, how do you enforce that the matrix $A$ is invertible in the second problem?